# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: php

i am trying to install a sdk on a public cloud service.The code is shown as follow:

```
<?php 
 echo ( '<meta charset="utf-8">');
date_default_timezone_set('PRC');
require_once __DIR__ . '/lib/KdtApiClient.php';

$appId = 'xxx';
$appSecret = 'xxx';
$client = new KdtApiClient($appId, $appSecret);


$method = 'kdt.users.weixin.followers.get';
$params = [
       // 'tid' => 'E20150126200526848473',
    //'num_iid' => 1005950256201501260011172648,
    //'title' => 'api 测试商品 编辑 __ 22',
    //'desc' => 'description here',
    //'post_fee' => 0.2,
    'page_size'=>5000,
];

$files = [
    [
        'url' => __DIR__ . '/file1.png',
        'field' => 'images[]',
    ],
    [
        'url' => __DIR__ . '/file2.jpg',
        'field' => 'images[]',
    ],
];


echo '<pre>';
var_dump( 
    $client->post($method, $params, $files)
);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

I got this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in php-sdk/index.php on line 12
```

The code works well on local xampp.Is there anyone can tell me what's the problem?

Comment: The public server is running a version of PHP below 5.4 where the only syntax for declaring an array is `$arr = array(...);`

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are encountering is most likely due to different PHP versions.

On line 12 you are using the short array syntax to create an array on the files variable. `$files = [`...
This syntax was introduced in [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) (See second point). However I think the cloud service is not using 5.4, which is why you don't have the short array syntax. The easy solution would be to use `$files = array(` instead.